# Normalization of Kallen-Lehmann spectral representation, comparison to 4D spectrum from 5D theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model

The Kallen–Lehmann spectral representation for a quantum field $\phi(x)$ is normalized:

$$\int_0^\infty d\mu^2\, \rho(\mu^2) = 1 \ ,$$

up to factors of $2\pi$ that are a matter of convention. See, for example, Ref [1] equation (9.51) or Ref [2] equation (10.7.18).

One way to derive this is to use the equal time commutation relation for the interacting field $\phi(x)$:

\begin{align}
\langle 0 | \left.[\phi(x),\pi(y)]\right|_{x^0= y^0} | 0 \rangle   
=\int_0^\infty d\mu^2\, \rho(\mu^2) \partial_{y^0} i \Delta(x-y ; \mu^2)
= \int_0^\infty d\mu^2\, \rho(\mu^2) i \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})
\end{align}
Since the left-hand side is $i \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$ from the equal time commutation relation, we end up with the above normalization for $\rho$.
We have used the spectral representation for the vev of the commutator, Ref. [1] eq. (9.56).

**Question:** does the normalization of $\rho(\mu^2)$ still hold when it is the spectrum between two composite operators $\mathcal O$? In this case it is not obvious to me that the equal time commutation relations are valid.

**Related question**: In Appendix A.1 of [arXiv:2105.07035](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07035), the authors derive a 4D continuum spectrum by assuming a scalar field in an infinite, flat extra dimension and looking at the two-point function on a 4D plane $z=0$, $\langle \Phi(x^\mu, z=0)\Phi(y^\mu, z=0)\rangle$. The resulting spectrum is
$$\rho(\mu) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\mu^2 +k^2}}$$
This spectrum is not obviously normalizable. Should it be? What goes wrong with the 4D equal time commutation relation argument above? Or is there some idea that the 5D theory is an infinite number of 4D fields which are separately normalized (e.g. in a Kaluza–Klein reduction of a compact extra dimension).

The second question relates to the first when modeling (as in the referenced paper) a 4D field with a continuum spectrum using a holographic extra dimension.

**References**:
[1] Greiner, *Field Quantization*, Chapter 9.4
[2] Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields*, Vol. 1 Chapter 10.7

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:** does the normalization of $\rho(\mu^2)$ still hold when it is the spectrum between two composite operators? In this case it is not obvious to me that the equal time commutation relations are valid.

The answer is no. This is addressed in version 3 of the manuscript [2105.07035](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07035v3), see the discussion around footnote 4:

> One important subtlety regarding the free continuum theory is that the canonical momentum $\Pi(x,t)$ can differ significantly from $\Phi$, since the Lagrangian corresponds to a higher derivative theory. Hence canonical quantization in terms of the field operator $\Phi$ becomes quite involved.

The Lagrangian is higher-derivative because the theory is non-local. From the holographic 5D perspective this is because one has integrated out the bulk propagation of the field.

The key point is that the normalization of $\rho(\mu^2)$ uses the equal time commutation relations between a field and its canonical momentum. When one is perturbing about a free theory, the canonical momentum is simply the time derivative of the field and one derives a normalization for $\rho$.

However, in a higher-derivative theory (or in general for a strongly coupled theory) the canonical momentum is not simply related to $\dot\Phi$ and this argument fails.

This point is further discussed towards the end of Section 6.2 of [2105.07035](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07035v3).